# c:forEach does not show data in correct order after ajax update

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, foreach, jstl

i m using jsf2 with primefaces and i have a refresh problem.

i have :

`<p:commandButton with ajax=true update="tableauObservatoire"`

`<p:outputPanel id="tableauObservatoire"`

into the p:outputpanel i have `<c:forEach...` to construct à table

when i arrived on the page, all data are correctly show.

when i click on my commandButton, action is well launched, and refresh look like ok, but into the table, data are not correctly ordered!! if i click again on p:commandbutton, data are well reorganized! i don't really understand what is happenning.

does i need to don't combine p:outputPanel with c:foreach? and use another combinaison in this case?

if you want more precision to answer, don't hesitate to ask me.

thanks a lot!

Comment: hello, i have transform all my c:foreach into ui:repeat, its work a litlle more correctly, ui:repeat doesn t support linkedhashmap so i transform it to list, but now i need to transform c:choose, i have use h:outputtext with rendered attribute but not working correctly :( what tag can i use properly? thanks

Comment: i have found the problem, in fact h:outputtext work fine but i can t use them for some reason, so i use h:panelGroup instead with attribute rendered and i put all i need into my panelGroup, h:panelGroup is correctly rendered after ajax update, next time i read a little more about built time and render time to don't loose your time...sorry and thank you for your help.